# Best way to analyze ~500K keys in Redis?

Tags: redis, lua, statistics, key

I have a database system which processes read operations against logical objects that are identified by OIDs (object identifiers). Example is 1.2.4.3.544. There are users identified by GUIDs. API gets results from DB and puts them into Redis. Key example is

```
SomePrefix_<oid>1.2.4.3.544</oid>_somedetails_<user>1f0c6cfe-ee9d-472c-b320-190df55f9527</user>
```

There are about a couple of hundreds unique OIDs in the system and about a hundred registered users. Also keys could not have user part for anonymous requests. Number of keys could vary from 80K to.. I suppose 500k.
I need to provide per-OID and per-user statistics to the UI and implement the possibility to delete-per-OID (the same for user). So the task is splitted into two. First version I had implemented was unsuccessful - I used .Keys("*") method in c# app which turns into Redis SCAN * to get all keys to the app to run through them, collect and distinct OIDs/users and show them on the UI. This operation was taking too much time to extract all keys to the app so I switched to another approach - on every save/delete key I incremented/decremented counters stored in Redis in another DB. Counters are simply integers with keys. This was almost okay but I got a requirement to set TTL for every cached request, so I faced with a dilemma how to store/track my statistics to keep it up-to-date with actually stored keys. Options I think

A) run LUA script to scan all keys and get all unique OIDS and unique users with counts, and return them to app. For deletion option - run SCAN inside LUA script and DEL all keys matched with pattern. Pros - no need for separate stats tracking. Cons - need to scan for all keys on every call. I have Zabbix dashboard to show statistics requested through my app and it could be painful to scan keys on every N seconds. These are cons.

B) In separate Redis DB store keys with sets where key is OID (or for users - key is GUID) and inside set store keys to cached requests. But how I could delete them when keys to cached requests are expired? Can I somehow link a value stored in a set with a key from another DB and make this value disappear from a set when key expires?

Comment: Did you check the Redis Module - RedisGears? It allows you to run Map-Reduce on Redis Cluster in Python. https://redisgears.io

Comment: No, I didn't. I will read about it tonight, thanks